# php, same data, same calculations, different results

Tags: php

I have the following code. At the end I put in comments the result I have on the server. Hope someone could explain me why the results are different, despite the calculations are the same.

```
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); 

function formatHourToTime($input){ 
    if (strpos($input, '.') !== false){ 
            $array = explode(".",$input); 
    } 
    elseif (strpos($input, ':') !== false){ 
            $array = explode(":",$input); 
    } 
    elseif (strpos($input, ',') !== false){ 
            $array = explode(",",$input); 
    } 
    elseif ($input >= '0' & $input < '24'){ 
            $array = array($input); 
    } 
    else { 
            $time = false; 
            exit(); 
    } 
    $time = $array[0]*3600+$array[1]*60+$array[2]; 
    return $time; 
} 

$matin_d = 0; //midnight timestamp 0.00 
$matin_f = 10800; //ts de 3h00 
$soir_d = 79200; //ts de 22h00 
$soir_f = 82799; //ts de 23h59:59 

function nightwork($start, $end){ 

    if ($start < $matin_f && $end > $soir_d) $totalheures = ($matin_f - $start)/2 + ($end - $soir_d)/2+100000; 
    elseif ($start < $matin_f && $end < $matin_f) $totalheures = ($end - $start)/2+200000; 
    elseif ($start >= $soir_d && $end > $soir_d) $totalheures = ($end - $start)/2+300000; 
    elseif ($start < $matin_f) $totalheures = ($matin_f-$start)/2+400000; 
    elseif ($end>$soir_d) $totalheures = ($end-$soir_d)/2+500000; 
    else $totalheures = 0+600000;  

    return $totalheures; 
} 

$start = formatHourToTime('07:39:00')*1; 

$end = formatHourToTime('08:00:00')*1; 
$shiftnw = nightwork($start, $end); 
if($start >= $soir_d && $end > $soir_f) $bool = 'true'; 
else $bool = 'false'; 
//même code que la fonction nightwork 
    if ($start < $matin_f && $end > $soir_d) $totalheures = ($matin_f - $start)/2 + ($end - $soir_d)/2+100000; 
    elseif ($start < $matin_f && $end < $matin_f) $totalheures = ($end - $start)/2+200000; 
    elseif ($start >= $soir_d && $end > $soir_d) $totalheures = ($end - $start)/2+300000; 
    elseif ($start < $matin_f) $totalheures = ($matin_f-$start)/2+400000; 
    elseif ($end>$soir_d) $totalheures = ($end-$soir_d)/2+500000; 
    else $totalheures = 0+600000;  

echo $start.' '.$end.'<br>'; 
echo $totalheures. ' ' .$shiftnw;  
//$totalheures is calculated following the script
//while $shiftnw is calculated by calling the function having the same lines 
// prints : 
// 27540 28800 
// 600000 300630 
?>
```

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use the core DateTime class to achieve whatever you're trying to do?  It can acheive virtually any format.  http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: Yes, I already tried to understand that class without success. Will try again in a few month when the daylight is longer ;)

Answer (score 1):

It appears the problem is that within the `nightwork()` function you do not have access to these variables:

```
$matin_d = 0; //midnight timestamp 0.00 
$matin_f = 10800; //ts de 3h00 
$soir_d = 79200; //ts de 22h00 
$soir_f = 82799; //ts de 23h59:59
```

Whereas you do have access to them in the global scope as calculated at the end of your script.

You would need to either place these values in the function as well, pass them to the function as parameters, declare them as `global` inside the function, or define them as constants to where they are available to all areas of your script regardless of scope.

Comment: This is it ! Thank you ! I added a line `code` global $matin_d, $matin_f, $soir_d, $soir_f; `code`, and it works ! Thanks a lot !